# "Due piedi in una scarpa" oppure "un piede in due scarpe"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, meaning

Ho guardato [questo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=EvNqzBHCdwc) nel quale si cerca di fare una rappresentazione letterale di alcuni modi di dire italiani. Nelle prime sequenze del video si vede un ragazzo che cerca di mettere due piedi in una scarpa. Ho cercato informazione sul modo di dire corrispondente a queste immagini e ho trovato questo in [Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossario_delle_frasi_fatte#D):

> **Due piedi in una scarpa/Due piedi in una staffa**
>
> Non decidersi tra due possibilità (ma è più corretta la frase "un piede in due scarpe"). Più usata invece col significato di sentirsi in difficoltà o in imbarazzo nei confronti di una persona per aver commesso qualcosa (stare con due piedi in una scarpa).

Come si deve dire? Avere due piedi in una scarpa? Avere un piede in due scarpe? Stare con due piedi in una scarpa? Stare con un piede in due scarpe?

Potreste anche chiarire il significato di questo modo (o modi) di dire?

Comment: non ho mai sentito prima "due piedi in una scarpa" ...

Comment: sinceramente nemmeno io, ma  sembra che sia usato. Pare quasi un errore di confusione (due piedi/due scarpe..), a rigor di logica *un piede in due scarpe* mi sembra l'espressione più corretta.

Comment: Sembra che in passato questo detto avesse un'interpretazione diversa: https://books.google.es/books?ei=CB1BVePDAcr3UpeQgVg&hl=ca&id=9ptDAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22due+piedi+in+una%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22messo+due+piedi+in+una%22 , https://books.google.es/books?id=NkVDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT430&dq=%22due+piedi+in+una%22&hl=ca&sa=X&ei=uCJBVbjxG4evU-bogOgD&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22due%20piedi%20in%20una%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=AcEgAQAAIAAJ&q=%22due+piedi+in+una+scarpa+(antico%22&dq=%22due+piedi+in+una+scarpa+(antico%22&hl=ca&sa=X&ei=MSxBVemDENGR7AaliID4Ag&ved=0CAoQ6AEwAA, https://books.google.es/books?id=jM5FAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA470&dq=%22due+piedi+in+una%22&hl=ca&sa=X&ei=iS1BVfioCuaC7gbQz4GYBA&ved=0CBkQ6AEwAzge#v=onepage&q=%22due%20piedi%20in%20una%22&f=false, veramente curioso.

Comment: Se è per questo, nel sud Italia, si usa anche dire *far di 3 zucche 2 fette*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secondo Treccani [piede/staffa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piede/):

> ***tenere il piede in due staffe*** (*meno comume tenere due piedi in una staffa, o anche tenere un piede in due scarpe, o due piedi in una scarpa*), ***tenere un contegno ambiguo***.

Tenere il piede in due staffe o in due scarpe sembrano essere le espressioni più usate (anche per quel che mi riguarda).

Come specificato si usa per indicare un comportamento ambiguo ma anche insicuro, quando non si sa o non ci si vuol decidere. ***Si usa spesso in riferimento ad un comportamento di comodo, per proprio vantaggio***.

- Franco non sa decidere  tra le due ragazze che frequenta. Per il momento sta con il piede in due scarpe.

*Secondo* [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=due%20piedi%20in%20una%2Cun%20piede%20in%20due&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdue%20piedi%20in%20una%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20piede%20in%20due%3B%2Cc0) *entrambe le versioni sono comunemente usate*.

Answer (score 2):

*Un piede in due scarpe* e *due piedi in una scarpa* sono espressioni equivalenti, secondo il [*Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piede/) (punto 2a).

Nella pubblicistica politica, si trovano tutt’e due le espressioni, talvolta con un significato particolare, ossia «tenere due incarichi tra loro incompatibili»:

> Parole forti, qualche imbarazzo, distinguo, accuse e precisazioni, ma
>   nella sostanza per alcuni degli esponenti più in vista del partito di
>   Epifani, De Luca non può più restare con **due piedi in una scarpa**. […]
>   Spiega il deputato europeo Andrea Cozzolino: «È un errore mantenere i
>   due incarichi […].» [[*La Repubblica*](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/2013/09/04/pd-in-pressing-su-de-luca-che.html), 4 settembre 2013]

In genere, però, il significato è «tenere un comportamento ambiguo o contraddittorio»:

> Il capo dell’Assemblea esecutiva di Belfast appena eletta, David
>   Trimble, è stato accusato da Gerry Adams, presidente del movimento
>   cattolico indipendentista Sinn Fein, di voler «**tenere un piede in due
>   scarpe**». Di invocare il dialogo, cioè, per poi «spargere il terrore»
>   nella regione agitando lo spettro di «tremende» conseguenze nel caso
>   di un ritorno al confronto civile. [[*La Repubblica*](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/1998/07/11/ulster-para-pronti-all-attacco.html), 11 luglio
>   1998]
>
> Ed è per questa stessa ragione che essi mi sembrano condannati a
>   **tenere** costantemente **un piede in due scarpe**; ad esempio, a non opporsi
>   al rifinanziamento della nostra missione militare in Iraq e a
>   partecipare alle marce di chi ne chiede il ritiro, beccandosi l’accusa
>   di «delinquenti politici» da Gino Strada. [[*Corriere della Sera*](http://archiviostorico.corriere.it/2004/marzo/13/interesse_liberale_per_riformisti_sinistra_co_9_040313054.shtml),
>   13 marzo 2004]
>
> Si può essere tifosi del Bari e nello stesso tempo di Milan, Inter o
>   Juventus? […] «Non si possono **avere due piedi in una scarpa**», il
>   concetto di Lele21, ribadito da nandolopiano che scrive che «il Bari
>   viene prima di tutto, nella gioia e nel dolore». [[*La
>   Repubblica*](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/2011/08/20/ira-degli-ultra-chi-tifa-biancorosso.html), 20 agosto 2011]

Answer (score -1):

A mio parere si potrebbe dire anche "tenere i piedi in due scarpe", naturalmente con un altro significato: per essere sicuro di non restare senza una scarpa in una posizione scomoda mi assicuro le posizioni e me le tengo strette...

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Una domanda a proposito del tuo post: questo "detto" con il significato che hai indicato veramente si usa? O si tratta invece di una tua invenzione?

Answer (score -2):

"Tenere il piede in due staffe o in due scarpe" mi sembrano espressioni chiarissime e le ho sempre sentite dire (sono un giovane 71enne). La versione dei due piedi in una scarpa non mi sembra per niente chiara e neanche tanto bella, oltre a indicare una cosa - di solito - fisicamente impossibile. Certo, potrei sempre chiedere al calzolaio di farmi una scarpa numero 82 ...

Answer (score -2):

Un piede in 2 scarpe = doppio gioco o doppia entrata
Due piedi in una scarpa =  avviso al fermarsi o momento di  di non possibilità